# TabBarController didSelectViewController not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I know this is a very repeat topic, but I can't get it works.

MainTab.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainTab : UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate> {

     IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabController;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabController;

@end
```

MainTab.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"main tab"); 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tabBarController.delegate = (id)self;
    [self setDelegate:self];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    NSLog(@"selected %d",tabBarController.selectedIndex);

}
```

I can't find what I'm missing, any help will be appreciated.

Now I try to link it into MainStoryBoard:

[image]

[image]

But it doesnt work, what are the connection?

Comment: How do have created `MainTab` object??

Comment: @Rob Yes, you are right - I somehow missed the "controller" part of the question, thinking it's a custom controller with a tab bar component. I deleted my comment, and voted for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the basis of your `@interface` (and your subsequent screen snapshot), `MainTab` is the `UITabBarController`, so the following line:

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = (id)self;
```

Should just be:

```
self.delegate = self;
```

You don't want a `tabBarController` property in the `UITabBarController`, itself, nor do you want to use the `self.tabBarController` syntax. You only use that syntax if you're trying to reference the tab bar controller from one of its children controllers. When in the tab bar controller itself, just refer to `self`.

---

Thus, it work if `MainBar` is defined as:

```
//  MainBar.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainBar : UITabBarController

@end
```

And

```
//  MainBar.m

#import "MainBar.h"

@interface MainBar () <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MainBar

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate = self;
}

-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"selected %d",tabBarController.selectedIndex);
}

@end
```

And don't forget to set the class of the tab bar controller:

[image: interface builder]

The connections inspector (where I didn't touch a thing) looks like:

[image: outlets]

Comment: No, I cant! when I try to control+drag I move the TabItems

Comment: MainTab was correctly set, I had a NSLog to check it, it was solved with your code

Comment: excellent answer. The key was to do it through code, nit the IB