# How do I call something in my UIViewController in the code of my UITabBarViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I want to call a method on a ViewController (type "MatchesViewController", which is on the 3rd tab of my TabBarViewControlleer) if the selected item is NOT of that class.

This is my delegate function for listening when a Tab Bar Item was changed.

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {

}
```

Inside this code, I'd like to detect if the item selected (and its View Controller) is of type "MatchesViewController".  If it is NOT of this type, then call method on that controller.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you give some more details for us non native english speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `tabBarController(_:didSelectViewController:)` ?

```
override func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController,
   didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) 
{
    if !(viewController is MatchesViewController) {
        let matchesVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?[2] as MatchesViewController
        matchesVC.refresh()
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this delegate method never gets called when I tap on the tabs?

Comment: How do you setup delegate? Maybe similar problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707207/tabbarcontroller-didselectviewcontroller-not-working ?

Comment: BTW `tabBarController(_:didSelectViewController:)` is `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method, not `UItabBarDelegate`

Comment: I fixed the delegate part, thanks :) But I'm having a problem with this line: let matchesVC = tabBarController.viewControllers[2] as MatchesViewController.  It says: "AnyObject is not convertible to Matches...".  I've tried to put a question mark or exclamation after "as", but doesn't seem to work either.